# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'SelectedCode') at LookupValue.aspx?Domain=7&Type=Unique:81:112

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, vb.net

Funtionality : We have a button named Select. when clicked, it opens a Modal with Gridview which has multiple options and has a select comamand in front of each option. Once clicked on Select command, Modal will get closed and the selected value will sit in textbox.

Problem: We have been using ShowModalDailog in our vb.net app and it was working fine until recent times. Suddenly we are not able to click on select button and open the Modal and choose a value from there.

Solutions tried:

1. Using 'open' in place of ShowModalDailog but it is opening a new tab all together and inner Select command is not working on click.
2. Using `<script src="https://unpkg.com/showmodaldialog"></script>`. Opens the Modal but again inner Select command is not working.

It is working in few of the labels but especially for listbox we are facing issues.

Please help with the required changes so that it is compatible with EDGE and GOOGLE CHROME browsers. Currently, application is being used in IE Mode.

Below is the code:

Select.aspx:

```
<tr height="20">
    <td style="width: 150px" valign="top" align="right">Unique Condition:
                            </td>
    <td valign="top" colspan="3">
        <asp:ListBox ID="lstUniqueConditions" runat="server" Width="375px"></asp:ListBox></td>
    <td valign="top">
        <input language="javascript" id="brnSelectUniqueCondition" onclick="btnSelectUniqueCondition_Click()"
            type="button" value="Select">
        <asp:Button ID="btnDeleteUniqueCondition" Width="52" runat="server" Text="Delete"></asp:Button></td>
</tr>

function btnSelectUniqueCondition_Click()
{
    var myObject = new Object();
    myObject.SelectedCode = "";
    myObject.SelectedValue = "";

    str = showModalDialog('LookupValue.aspx?Domain=7&Type=Unique',myObject,'font-size:10px;dialogWidth:80em;dialogHeight:50em');
    document.getElementById('SelectItem_UniqueConditionPKId').value = myObject.SelectedCode;
    document.getElementById('SelectItem_UniqueConditionSelect').click();
}
```

LookupValue.aspx.vb:

```
Private Sub grdLookupSelect_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridCommandEventArgs) Handles grdLookupSelect.ItemCommand
    Select Case (CType(e.CommandSource, LinkButton)).CommandName
        Case "Select"
            divScripts.InnerHtml = "<script language=javascript>var oMyObject = window.dialogArguments;oMyObject.SelectedCode=""" & HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(e.Item.Cells(0).Text) & """;oMyObject.SelectedValue=""" & HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(e.Item.Cells(1).Text) & """;window.close();</script>"
        Case Else
            ' Do nothing.
    End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a gridview in your markup?
(I assume it is the other page that you pop up).

Regardless, from Mozella (firefox), Chrome (google, Microsoft Edge) have all announced this feature was to be deprecated from their browsers. (and these announcements started about 2013 (almost 10 years ago).

So, really you not going to have any real luck attempting to fix, or using showdialog. it is gone, and will not return.

However, all is not lost. You can use popular "dialog" routines to pop a dialog. Keep in mind that these systems work in the CURRENT page.

And more imporant, the older showdialog blocks JavaScript - that kind of code is simply not allowed anymore (it can and does cause the browser to freeze up - and that's simply not allowed anymore).

Then, what to do?

I suggest about the best (and least disruption) to browser code would be to adopt jquery.UI. Quite much every site these days uses jQuery, and thus adding the small jQuer.UI library makes the most sense. In jQuery.UI is a very nice dialog routine - and that's what I use now.

The only real challenge is all of "any" new browser code is of course non-blocking. (that means the browser code does not halt anymore and freeze up the browser. It thus also means that the only two features left in a browser that blocks and halts code is "alert()" and "confirm()".

So, thus, to replace your code?

Your best bet is jQuery.UI and from jQuery.UI use the dialog feature.

it does mean your existing JavaScript bits have to be broken into two steps.

First step: pop the dialog.

When the user makes a choice, you then hit ok or whatever to close the dialog and then call some more code (a 2nd routine to continue). So, in place of code right after the dialog display, you now will (must have) a 2nd js routine that runs when the dialog is closed.

This also means (in most cases), that dialog you pop ALSO cannot have post-backs in the page you pop as a dialog. You can get around this, but if possible, one should hope that the dialog you display does not have buttons with post-backs (or, if they do, then you assume that post-back will close/collapse the dialog).

So, let's say I have a text box, and a button. The button will "pop" a gridview (on that other page). User will select from that GV, and then "ok" to continue.

In MOST cases, that dialog should be based on a simple dialog that exists in the current page (in a div). However, you CAN pop a dialog that is another page, but as noted, this means/suggests that post-backs should not occur in that dialog you display (or at the very least only one post-back for a final operation).

One more FYI:

The "click" event on that page you open? the JavaScript code for that click is in the CURRENT page!!!!

Remember, the jQuery.UI dialog actually "loads" that WHOLE web page into this page!!!

so, lets show how this works:

First page, a simple text box and button. We can type into the box a hotel name, OR WE can pop up another page with a gridview of choices, user will then select/pick/choose a hotel from the grid view.

So, our page and markup look like this:

```
        <h3>Enter or Select Hotel Name</h3>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server" Width="248px" 
            style="margin-right:15px" ClientIDMode="Static">

        </asp:TextBox>

         <button id="cmdSave" runat="server" class="btn myshadow" type="button"
             onclick="pophotel(this);return false;">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"> Pick&ensp;Hotel</span> 
        </button>

        <div id="popdiv">
        </div>

        <script>
            function pophotel(Btn) {

                var myDialog = $("#popdiv");
                myDialog.dialog({
                    title: "Please Select a Hotel",
                    width: "40%",
                    modal: true,
                    autoOpen: false,
                    dialogClass: 'ui-widget-shadow',
                    appendTo: "form",
                    position: { my: "left top", at: "right bottom", of: Btn },

                    buttons: [
                        {
                            text: 'Cancel',
                            class: 'myshadow',
                            click: function () {
                                myDialog.dialog('close')
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                })
                myDialog.load("MyGrid.aspx")
                myDialog.dialog("open")


            }

            function myselect(sHotel) {
                var myDialog = $("#popdiv");
                myDialog.dialog('close')
                $('#txtHotel').val(sHotel)
            }
        </script>
```

Now I ONLY used a "button" in place of a asp.net button since I wanted to use the gylph-icon. (those are from bootstrap - but they have been depreicated since bootstrap 4+).

Ok, so in above is rather simple.

now, the page I am going to load is a clean page, but with a grid view.

That page is this gridview.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover"  >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="Hotel Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="cmdEdit" runat="server" Text="Select" 
                        CssClass="btn myshadow"
                        OnClientClick='<%# "myselect(""" + Eval("HotelName").ToString + """);return false;" %>'
                         />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</form>
```

Ok, and code in that page to load the gv is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
            Dim strSQL =
                "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName"

            Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
                conn.Open()
                Dim rstData As New DataTable
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
                GridView1.DataSource = rstData
                GridView1.DataBind()
            End Using
        End Using

    End If
End Sub
```

So, the results are now this:

[image]